# Woher kommt die Redewendung „Hast du sie noch alle“?

Tags: idiom, pronoun, slang

Die Bedeutung ist hier „Bist du verrückt?“, aber worauf bezieht sich das Pronomen *sie* in diesem Satz?

Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob das Pronomen etwas mit dem Satz „Du hast wohl einen Vogel“ zu tun hat. Falls ja, warum heißt es *sie* und nicht *ihn*, oder bezieht es sich auf den Plural des Worts *Vogel?*

Comment: Ich werfe »Du hast nicht mehr alle Tassen im Schrank!«, als potenziellen Herkunftsvorschlag in den Ring.

Comment: Ich unterstütze diesen Kommentar. Es ist vermutlich eine Verkürzung von _nicht mehr alle (Tassen im Schrank) haben_.

Comment: Aber Entschuldigung , was hat dieser Satz (Tassen im Schrank)mit der Verrücktheit zu tun ?

Comment: oder meinst du , dass man mit dem Trinken noch nicht fertig  ist , und dass alle Tassen zurückgebracht werden sollen !?.

Comment: Nein, *nicht mehr alle Tassen im Schrank haben* ist auch ein umgangssprachlicher Ausdruck für *verrückt sein*.

Comment: Das ist ja doch klar , aber ich habe versucht zu verstehen , wie diese Redewendung gebildet worden ist . Tassen im Schrank beziehen sich auf die Situationen , in denen man Alkohol trinkt , und nicht mehr  bewusst sein kann , d.h verrückt sein !?

Comment: *Das* ist eine sehr gute Frage … ^^' Übrigens kannst du Leute mit @Name pingen; dann kriegen sie einen Hinweis, dass ihnen geantwortet wurde. Der Besitzer des Posts (in diesem Fall du) wird automatisch gepingt.

Comment: @Jan: Pingen? Besitzer des Posts? Was hälst Du von 'Autor, Schreiber, Verfasser, Absender'?

Comment: @userunknown Da trifft mich doch der Übersetzerschlag ;) Nein, *pingen* halte ich für ähnlich kurz und klar wie *antippen* und bei *Besitzer* ist mir sicherlich *post owner* im Kopf durchgegangen … Aber es gibt relevanteres, über das wir uns unterhalten können ;)

Comment: @Jan: Ich werde aber nicht gepingt. Ein Ping prüft gleich und nur sofort die Anwesenheit eines Knotens. Hier bekomme ich aber eine Nachricht sobald ich mich wieder anmelde. Zu Postowner möchte ich führnehmst schweigen. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basierend auf  den Kommentaren und dieser [Seite](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~sie%20nicht%20mehr%20alle%20haben&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou) würde ich meine Frage beantworten.

Ich zitiere:

> Zunächst könnte man vermuten, dass hier die „Tassen im Schrank“ metaphorisch für die Voraussetzungen stehen, die man für vernünftiges Handeln braucht, wenn sie fehlen, handelt man eben nicht vernünftig. Eine Deutung bezieht sich auf das jiddische Wort „toschia“, was „Verstand, Klugheit“ bedeutet und volksetymologisch zur „Tasse“ wurde; der Schrank als Behältnis für die Tassen würde hier für den Kopf als Behältnis für den Verstand stehen.

Das scheint mir bisschen mehr vernünftig zu sein.

Comment: Die Herleitung aus dem Jiddischen kommt mir sehr plausibel vor, dazu gibt es sogar den [Wikipedia-Artikel *Nicht alle Tassen im Schrank haben](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicht_alle_Tassen_im_Schrank_haben)

Comment: Äh, nur leider ist das die Antwort auf die falsche Frage. Es ging nicht nach der Herkunft der "Tassen im Schrank", sondern wofür "alle" steht in der Version "nicht mehr alle haben". Was referenziert "alle"?

Answer (score 5):

Wie du schon erkannt hast, ist „Hast du sie noch alle?“ eine Redewendung und *sie* hat daher nicht wirklich eine Bedeutung. Ich würde „Hast du noch alle Tassen im Schrank?“ als Herkunft sehen, das *sie* würde sich dann auf die Tassen beziehen, welche wiederum für die Gedanken der angesprochenen Person stehen, im Sinne von „Hast du deine Gedanken noch alle beisammen?“

Comment: Ich zweifel die Theorie mit den Tassen sehr an. Warum nicht die sprichwörtlichen "Latten am Zaun", "Nadeln an der Tanne", "Kekse in der Dose" oder die Christbaum-Variante? — Oder vielleicht auch von "nicht mehr alle Sinne beisammen haben". Dies wäre zumindest mein Favorit.

Comment: @Em1 könnte aber sein, dass *Latten am Zaun* usw. Variationen sind, wir kennen das von *auf den Geist gehen* -> *auf den Zünder gehen* (neben Zünder gibt es eine unüberschaubare Menge von Alternativen: Sack, Kranz, Ketten, ...)

Comment: @Wolf Da hast du mit Sicherheit recht. Vermutlich sind die Tassen die älteste aller dieser Variante. Noch älter werden aber wohl "die Sinne" sein, und das war ja immerhin mein Favorit :p

Comment: @Em1 Nicht schlecht! Wer weiß schon, wann die "Tassen" die Bühne betraten.

Answer (score 1):

Ich vermute "Hast du sie noch alle?" geht zurück auf "Hast du noch alle Sinne beisammen?". Der Ausdruck mit den Tassen im Schrank ist nur ein phantasievolles Vergleichsbild zu der ursprünglichen Form (alle Sinne). Wir sagen auch "Bist du von Sinnen?". Für die Idee "Spinnst du?" gibt es wohl hundert Varianten und laufend werden neue Varianten gebildet. "verrückt" ist eben eine häufig gebrauchte
Idee. Es wäre interessant, all diese Varianten wie "Bei dir piepsts wohl, Dachschaden, Du tickst ja nicht mehr richtig etc genauer zu untersuchen.