# Alle Tassen im Schrank haben

Tags: etymology, phrase

Wo kommt der Ausdruck „nicht mehr alle Tassen im Schrank haben“ her? Bedeutet ja meines Wissens das jemand nicht mehr ganz dicht ist.

Wenn man nicht alle Tassen im Schrank hat, sind einige Tassen zB. am Tisch oder anderswo … bedeutet für mich eher, dass man zerstreut ist.
Für mich klingt das nach unordentlich, im Sinne von nicht ordnungsliebend.

Der Ausdruck wird aber als Synonym für *nicht ganz dicht* genutzt.

Wo kommt dann der Ausdruck her?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25962/woher-kommt-die-redewendung-hast-du-sie-noch-alle

Comment: @Takkat eher keine Dublette meiner Ansicht. Wobei eine Antwort auf die potenzielle Etymologie der Tassen im Schrank eingeht.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Von jemandem, den man für verrückt hält, sagt man, dass er **nicht alle Tassen im Schrank** habe. Der Ausdruck Tasse hat dabei nichts mit dem homonymen Wort Tasse als Trinkgefäß zu tun, sondern es leitet sich von dem **jiddischen Wort toshia** her, das so viel wie Verstand bedeutet. ([Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicht_alle_Tassen_im_Schrank_haben))

Comment: Ich denke dies ist eine hilfreiche ERgänzung http://www.redensarten.net/Tassen.html