# sie nicht mehr alle haben

Tags: meaning

I have heard the following dialogue in the TV series Dark:

- Da, wo ich herkomme, haben du und ich die gleiche Vergangenheit.
- Du hast sie doch nicht mehr alle.

What does "sie nicht mehr alle haben" mean in this sentence? "to be crazy" ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Woher kommt die Redewendung „Hast du sie noch alle“?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25962/woher-kommt-die-redewendung-hast-du-sie-noch-alle)

Comment: @Glorfindel: The referenced question is pure German however, while I consider this as mostly English.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word order is

**sie nicht mehr alle haben**.

And the meaning is, as you mention, to be crazy. It might be a short or related form of

**nicht mehr alle Tassen im Schrank haben** (and many more variations of similar structure).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! FYI I have fixed the word order in the question.

Answer (score 2):

As you have already recognized, "Do you still have them all?" (*Hast du sie noch alle?*) is an idiom (**are you crazy?**) and therefore it does not really have any meaning. I would see "Do you still have all cups in the cupboard?" (*Hast du noch alle Tassen im Schrank?*) as origin, which would then refer to the cups, which in turn represent the thoughts of the person addressed, in the sense of "Do you still have all your thoughts together?" (*Hast du deine Gedanken noch alle beisammen?*)

Comment: There seem to be several expression this could be derived from: *nicht alle Tassen im Schrank haben*, *nicht alle auf der Latte haben*, *nicht alle Nadeln auf der Tanne haben*, but without context I think the actual meaning is somewhat ambiguous since it might actually mean "You don't have all of them," in a different scenario. Maybe the best translation in this case is simply "You've lost it!"